# When does the CLR create the IO thread when I call BeginXXX()

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, io

Suppose I call HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream() method.

I know that this method is asynchronous and when it's finished, an callback method should be called.

What I'm very sure is that when call the callback method, an I/O thread is created by CLR and this I/O thread do the callback.

What I'm not sure is when I call HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(), is there any I/O thread created by CLR? Or just a worker thread created to send the request to the device?

Comment: A good reading http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: It is unproductive to think this way.  There is no thread.  BeginXxx() simply asks the TCP/IP driver stack to start an operation.  Only when the driver completes the request, in response to data being received on the network card, does a thread spring to life to make the call to your callback method.  Which the obvious advantage of not having any threads sitting around gobbling a megabyte of memory doing nothing but waiting.  Google "i/o completion ports" to learn more.

Comment: So can I think that, when calling HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream() method, it's synchronous. This calling just send the request to the device drivers and return instantly.It happens in the main thread. There's no thread created at this time. Until the IO Operation is finished, there's a I/O thread waked to call the callback. All that thing I think are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Async IO is thread-less.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) There is no thread being created or blocked. That is the entire point of using async IO! What would it help you to unblock one thread and block another?

The internals of this have been discussed many times. Basically, the OS notifies the CLR when the IO is done. This causes the CLR to queue the completion callback you specified onto the thread-pool.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You don't care.

Long answer:

There is no thread. More exactly, there is no thread for each of the asynchronous request you create. Instead, there's a bunch of I/O threads on the thread pool, which are mostly "waiting" on IOCP - waiting for the kernel to wake them up when data is available.

The important point is that each of these can respond to any notification, they're not (necessarily) selective. If you need to process 1000 responses, you can still do so with just the one thread - and it is only at this point that a thread from the thread pool is requested; it has to execute the callback method. For example, using synchronous methods, you'd have to keep a thousand threads to handle a thousand TCP connections.

Using asynchronous methods, you only need the one IOCP thread, and you only have to spawn (or rather, borrow) new threads to execute the callbacks - which are only being executed after you get new data / connection / whatever, and are returned back to the thread pool as soon as you're done. In practice, this means that a TCP server can handle thousands of simultaneous TCP connections with just a handful of threads. After all, there's little point in spawning more threads than your CPU can handle (which these days is usually around twice as much as you've got cores), and all the things that don't require CPU (like asynchronous I/O) *don't require you to spawn new threads*. If the handful of processing threads isn't enough, adding more will not help, unlike in the synchronous I/O scenario.